# How to get selected items from custom listview and print that in toast message?

Tags: android, xml, listview

Here i am trying to get selected items from custom listview for showing them in next activity but I don't have any idea about how to get selected item from custum list view 
providing codes of my project.
Product.java(Fragment)

```
`package com.example.chavda.agency_managment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Product extends Fragment {
    ListView product_list;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // getActivity().setTitle(R.string.attandance);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product, container, false);
        product_list = v.findViewById(R.id.product_list);
        final downloader d = new downloader(getContext(), product_list);
        d.execute();
        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
        final CustomHelper p = new CustomHelper();


        product_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                try {

                    //SingleRow temp = p.list.get(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + product_list.getItemIdAtPosition(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

single_row_product.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:focusable="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/productimage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"

            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/namep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sizep"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sizep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:focusable="false"

                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="TextView"

                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"

            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sizep"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="TextView"

                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:focusable="false"

                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

here is 
product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/product_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The solution you provide, it will be great help for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to tap on each item and click a button to move to the next fragment and show all selected then you just need to keep a list of selected items and add/remove the item on the onListItemClicked you have.

If you want to have checkboxes and all the fancy stuff then you’re going to have to create a custom BaseAdapter, supply it with a list and a XML for the cell and then do all the handling there and retrieve the list from the adapter before you move to the next fragment